# why I cannot use foreach in mapPartitions in Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

I created an array using `SparkContext` using 2 partitions, I also try to use `mapPartition` to handle the elements, however I've got a very strange error, when I code like this:

```
val masterURL = "local[*]"

val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("KMeans Test").setMaster(masterURL)
val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
sc.setLogLevel("WARN")

val data = sc.textFile("file:/d:/data/kmeans_data.txt")
val parsedData = data.mapPartitions(partition => parseData(partition)).cache()

parsedData.mapPartitions(points =>
  points.map(point =>
    println(point)
  )
)
```

It has no errors, however, when I replace map to foreach, it tips an error:

```
parsedData.mapPartitions(points =>
  points.foreach(point =>
   println(point)
  )
)
```

the error is as follows:

> Type mismatch, expected: (Iterator[Vector]) => Iterator[NotInferedU],
>   actual: (Iterator[Vector]) => Unit Expression of type Unit doesn't
>   conform to expected type Iterator[U_]

In addition, the first code snip also do not print anything in console panel, why?

Comment: When you use the foreach method, you are returning `Unit`. Try returning the `points` Iterator in `mapPartitions`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

mapPartitions expect a function that return a new iterator of partitions (`Iterator[Vector] => Iterator[NotInferedU]`), it maps an iterator to another iterator.
By using foreach you return void (Unit in Scala) which is different from the expected return type.

For printing RDD content, you can use `foreachPartition` instead of `mapPartitions`:

```
parsedData.foreachPartition(points =>
  points.foreach(point =>
    println(point)
  )
)
```

Answer (score 3):

You're getting this error because the `foreach`method returns `Unit`type. The `mapPartitions` method cannot return that type. Try returning the same iterator you are receiving:

```
parsedData.mapPartitions(points =>
  points.foreach(point =>
   println(point)
  )
  points
)
```

It should work.

> In addition, the first code snip also do not print anything in console panel, why?

Because the map function does not execute anything until an action is called, (for example, `collect` or `foreach`).